# Objective-C cast a block type into another got unexpected result

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point, objective-c-blocks, forecasting

`typedef (void (^blockType)());`

I need cast blocks with different argument types into a same type `blockType`, and invoke it as the original type later. But there is a issue while casting block type.

The following code works well with any argument type, ...

```
((blockType)^(BOOL b) {
    NSLog(@"BOOL: %d", b);
})(YES); // >> BOOL: 1
((blockType)^(int i) {
    NSLog(@"int: %d", i);
})(1); // >> int: 1
((blockType)^(double f) {
    NSLog(@"double: %f", f);
})(1.0 / 3); // >> double: 0.333333
((blockType)^(NSString *s) {
    NSLog(@"NSString *: %@", @"string");
})(1.0 / 3); // >> NSString *: string
```

**except float**:

```
((blockType)^(float f) {
    NSLog(@"float: %f", f);
})(1.0f); // >> float: 0.000000
((blockType)^(float f) {
    NSLog(@"float: %f", f);
})(1.0f / 3); // >> float: 36893488147419103232.000000
```

but it is ok without casting:

```
(^(float f) {
    NSLog(@"float without casting: %f", f);
})(1.0 / 3); // >> float without casting: 0.333333
```

how to explain and resolve it?

Comment: How to resolve it? Don't do this :)

Comment: @jtbandes You are right :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explain: Calling the block as `blockType`- `(void (^)())`, the block is treated as `(void (^)(double))`.

Resolve: Must cast the block back to `(void (^)(float))` when invoking.

Comment: It's always dangerous to call a function via a function pointer (or block pointer) of a different type.

Comment: The ABI is different for different number and types of parameters. Which registers or parts of the stack are used for passing values and which are used for returning values and different, and the ABI is different on different architectures. I don't believe there's any safe way to ensure that your function setups and preambles are going to be compatible with what you're trying to do. The answer is don't do this. The usual solution is to make every function accept a single `id` (object). Then wrap whatever you need to pass into that object (NSNumber, NSDictionary, whatever).

Answer (score 4):

It appears to be a taint of the good old C language. Consider the following code (we can say it is kind of 'translation' of your Obj-C block with issues to C as far as blocks are related to function pointers ([see here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html))):

```
void test()
{
    void (*pEmpty)();
    pEmpty = functionFloat;
    pEmpty(1.0f / 3);
}

void functionFloat(float f)
{
    printf("float: %f", f);
}
```

If you call `test` you will see the same result as when you invoke your 'sick' block. Compiler will provide just a warning about incompatible pointers and will let you run. But if you change

`void (*pEmpty)();`

to

`void (*pEmpty)(void);`

there will be a compile-time error. Same will happen if you add `void` explicitly to your void-blocks, e.g. `(void (^)(void)` instead of `(void (^)()`.

The reason for such behavior explained in the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The empty list in a function declarator that is not part of a
>   definition of that function specifies that **no information** about the number or types of the
>   parameters is supplied.
> §6.7.6.3-14  (p.134)

Thus, as it doesn't mean that there are **no parameters** but rather **no info** about them, cast passes fine.

The problem with unexpected output is the following:

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another
>   type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted
>   pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type,
>   the behavior is undefined.
> §6.3.2.3-8  (p.56)

and

> If the function is defined with a type that is not compatible with the type (of the
>   expression) pointed to by the expression that denotes the called function, the behavior is
>   undefined.
> §6.5.2.2-9  (p.82)

So, it seems that the solution here is just like @jtbandes said: don't mess block types and re-design this part of code to avoid such casts.